# Android - how can i make a list of matching items as an entry is typed in

Tags: android, autocomplete

I'm very new to programming, so be gentle.

My goal is to make a simple app that as you type in a search term, it will list all entries from a database that start with those letters. Basically it's a listing of all auto-complete options that fit what has been typed in so far from a database of words.

I'm just trying to get an idea as to how to approach this task. Any helpful code would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has that all worked out. You want to use the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Here is Android's [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) to get you started with their AutoCompleteTextView.